# Unicode supported isdigit and isspace function

Tags: c++, unicode

I have the following code.

```
// mfc.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mfc.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Strsafe.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

std::wstring toStringWithoutNumerical(const std::wstring& str) {
    std::wstring result;

    bool alreadyAppendSpace = false;
    for (int i = 0, length = str.length(); i < length; i++) {
        const TCHAR c = str.at(i);
        if (isdigit(c)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (isspace(c)) {
            if (false == alreadyAppendSpace) {
                result.append(1, c);
                alreadyAppendSpace = true;
            }
            continue;
        }
        result.append(1, c);
        alreadyAppendSpace = false;
    }

    return result;
}


// The one and only application object

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
    }

    std::wstring me = toStringWithoutNumerical(_T("My Leg 1 Long"));
    AfxMessageBox(me.c_str());

    // Crash!
    std::wstring he = toStringWithoutNumerical(L"我的脚1盘");
    AfxMessageBox(he.c_str());

    return nRetCode;
}
```

For 1st message box,

**My Leg Long**

will be shown.

For 2nd message box, crash will happen, with assertion fail at isctype.c

```
_ASSERTE((unsigned)(c + 1) <= 256);
```

How I can get a standard function (isdigit, isspace...), to support unicode out of 256 range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iswdigit?

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/iswdigit.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc4ksh8(VS.71).aspx

also, look up iswspace ;)

Comment: Only, the documentation says `in the program's current locale`, even for `iswdigit()` and `iswspace()`. Am I to ignore that sentence? Or is that because a few Unicode characters react differently to a few locale? (i.e. Turkish I to ı, and İ to i.)

Answer (score 2):

There are also a C++ template, locale-aware versions of [isspace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/isspace/) and [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/isdigit/), located in `<locale>` header if you want to go multiplatform.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle Unicode characters is extremely complex. However, if you just want to check a few character categories, you can generally make do without too much trouble.

The Unicode interface in POSIX (Unix) is `u_isXYZ()` such as `u_isspace()`.

http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/index.html

```
#include <unicode/uchar.h>

...
if(u_isspace(c))
{
   ... // this is a space character
}
...
```

From what I can see the ICU library is available under MS-Windows so you should be able to use it too.

Remember, though, that `wchar_t` under MS-Windows is only 16 bits, so you have to handle surrogates yourselves (values between `0xD800` and `0xDFFF` represent characters between `0x10000` and `0x10FFFF`--although those are not used as much if you do not deal with Asian languages).

The `iswspace()` function is locale bound and will definitively not return the same results as the proper Unicode functions.